# Mypy produces incompatible signature error but Liskov Substitution Principle is satisfied

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

The following inheritance structure satisfies the Liskov Substitution Principle (i.e., in this case, accepting any kwargs and not accepting any non-keyword args).

```
class Parent:
    def mymethod(self, **kwargs) -> None:
        print("Called Parent mymethod")
    
class Child(Parent):
    def mymethod(self, *, arg1: int, **kwargs) -> None:
        print("Called Child mymethod")
```

However, mypy produces an error:

`error: Signature of "mymethod" incompatible with supertype "Parent"`

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Parent`'s `mymethod` claims to take a minimum of 0 keyword arguments. To understand this, take a look at this example:

```
def mymethod(**kwargs) -> None:
    pass

mymethod()
```

`mypy` reports success for this because no named keyword arguments are required. `len(kwargs)` here is 0.

Your example shows that `Child`'s `mymethod` takes a minimum of 1 keyword argument, because `arg1` is forced to be provided. For:

```
def mymethod(*, named_kwarg, **kwargs) -> None:
    pass 

mymethod()
```

`mypy` reports:

```
error: Missing named argument "named_kwarg" for "mymethod"
```

Do you now see why your error occurs? Your `Parent`'s `mymethod` declares a minimum of 0 keyword arguments. Your `Child`s `mymethod` declare a minimum of 1 keyword argument. Liskov's Substitution Principle says that an instance of a superclass should be replaceable with an instance of the subclass, but since your subclass imposes stricter requirements than the superclass, `mypy` errors for your type hierarchy.

If `mypy` reported success, passing 0 keyword arguments would cause a runtime error if the instance of `Parent` you're dealing with also happened to be an instance of `Child`.

To further drive home the point, if we change `Child`'s `mymethod` signature to:

```
def mymethod(self, *, arg1: Optional[int] = None, **kwargs) -> None:
    ...
```

`mypy` now shows no error for your hiearchy. This is because we've declared `mymethod` to take a minimum of now 0 keyword arguments instead of 1, making it as flexible as `Parent` requires under Liskov's Substitution Principle.

Comment: Although the error goes away for the signature, using `arg1: Optional[int] = None` means that your code needs to handle `arg1=None`. If this is handled by raising `ValueError`, then you will be violating LSP (precondition cannot strengthen the subtype). Getting stuck with this is usually a sign of code smell, and that `Child` should not be a subtype of `Parent`. It is often suggested to replace it with composition or a new/different superclass.

Comment: @Keto Agreed, Python makes prohibiting LSP violation difficult even with mypy because the way to conventionally signal an error completely escapes the type system. Languages that encourage error values over exceptions (Rust, Go) come close to prohibiting LSP violation, but they still have `panic` that escapes the type system.